# how to conditionally run different command with same arguments

Tags: bash, shell, tar

if gtar is defined I want to use that, instead of tar:

```
if command -v gtar; then
  gtar --exclude-ignore='.deployignore' -cf /dev/stdout . | aws s3 cp - "$arti_fact"
else
  tar --exclude-ignore='.deployignore' -cf /dev/stdout . | aws s3 cp - "$arti_fact"
fi
```

however this is sinning as far as DRY. Is there some way to run different command with same args conditionally?

Comment: What if `gtar` isn't installed, and `tar` is not GNU tar and doesn't recognize the `--exclude-ignore` option? Anyways, you could do that simply as `"$(command -v gtar || command -v tar || echo /no/tar/on/this/machine)" --exclude-ignore= ... | ...` (unlike your command, this will _not_ run a `tar` or `gtar` function, if such is defined ;-)).

Comment: I think tar will exit with 1 if it doesn't recognize the --exclude-ignore opt?

Comment: Maybe it will -- in which case your script will break and the user will be left holding both pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the command you want to use in a variable:

```
tar=tar
if command -v gtar; then tar=gtar; fi
"$tar" --exclude-ignore='.deployignore' -cf /dev/stdout . | aws s3 cp - "$arti_fact"
```

Comment: ahh I didn't know you could just store it as variable, I thought you might have to do some eval type stuff